# hcitool lescan Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, ubuntu-18.04, bluez

the following command

```
sudo hcitool lescan
```

throws the following error:

```
Set scan parameters failed: Input/output error
```

I have tried

```
hciconfig hci0 down
hciconfig hci0 up
```

and then

```
service bluetooth restart
service dbus restart
```

and tried againg. still didnt work.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
bluez version: 5.48

Comment: did you use ```sudo``` for all the commands?

Comment: yes all the commands are running as superuser

Comment: What's the output of "hciconfig -a"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60322966/5616255